# Tabs Not Showing in Ionic 2

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-view

I have a tab inside a modal. I need to show the 3 tabs inside the modal. However, it doesn't show up. It just appear a blank.

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
    <ion-buttons left>
      <button ion-button icon-only (click)="closeModal()">
        <ion-icon name="arrow-back"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title class="filter">Filter</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab>Hello</ion-tab>
  <ion-tab>Hello</ion-tab>
  <ion-tab>Hello</ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Your question already answered here in So [ion tab in model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46047598/ionic-3-tabs-on-modal)

Comment: Using [`Segments`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/segment/Segment/) wouldn't be a better approach? It may be possible to use tabs inside of a modal, but it sounds like a hack...

Comment: @sebaferreras. Yeah i used it. Much easier. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are putting `ion-tabs` inside `ion-content`. [ion-tabs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/tabs/Tabs/) is a container for a number of `ion-tab` components which contain a navigation stack of its own. This container cannot be nested in `ion-content` and needs to be a component of its own.

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab>Hello</ion-tab>
  <ion-tab>Hello</ion-tab>
  <ion-tab>Hello</ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

From a stackblitz test code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-qdlccw?file=pages%2Ftabs%2Ftabs.html) you *could* try to have a common header above the ion-tabs. But you may need to adjust some css for the individual pages to have space from the header. Or you can set the header separately for each individual page:

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
    <ion-buttons left>
      <button ion-button icon-only (click)="closeModal()">
        <ion-icon name="arrow-back"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title class="filter">Filter</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

in your tab.